# Advantages and disadvantages of using "()" while calling function in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, methods, invoke

There are explanations about the JavaScript methods "call" and "apply"  in many places. However, I couldn't find any explanation about invoking functions using `()`.
For instance:

```
var a = function(arg){  
    //arg.call();
    //arg.apply();
    //arg();
}

var myParam = function() {
    //do someting 
}

var instance = new a(myParam);
```

Which way should I use? What are the disadvantages of calling a method using `()`?

Comment: I believe the question isn't hard to understand, but your sample code has nothing to do with your question at all. In the other hand, I honestly believe that there're tons of sites and questions which you can check to answer that's `apply(...)` and so on!!!!

Comment: Well, you'd type more characters for no real benefit. That would be bad for code readability.

Comment: If you call the function normally, you can not set the value of `this`. Other than that, `.apply()` allows you to set a dynamic amount of arguments.

Comment: @Tims please paste a snippet.

Comment: @MatíasFidemraizer just give a link of one page that investigate () case with apply and call

Comment: @user1645941 Request failed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Options

There are three ways to call functions.

```
Direct: myFunction(Object arg1, Object arg2, ...);
Call:   myFunciton.call(Object this, Object arg1, Object arg2, ...);
Apply:  myFunction.apply(Object this, Array args);
```

Each has it's own features. The only disadvantage of `call()` and `apply()` *could* be that their performance is bad. After some research it turned out that they are a tiny bit slower than calling a function direct. Though so little that it's not even worth considering.

### What to pick?

Because there are no huge disadvantages, we can pick a method by judging the *advantages* only. That means, comparing the features and picking whatever suits your case.

### `.call();`

Unlike calling a function directly, `.call()` allows you to set the `this` keyword. Apart from that it's practically the same. So why would you want to set the `this` keyword? Have a look at the following example.

```
var element = document.getElementById('my-element');

doSomething(element, function(success) {
    if(success) {
        // something succeeded!

        // because I passed "element" as "this",
        // I can use "this" to do more stuff with "element"
        this.style.display = 'none';
    }
});


function doSomething(element, callback) {
    // do something with element

    // I'm done, let's call the callback
    callback.call(element, success);
}
```

As you can see, the `this` in the callback argument refers to the element we have been playing with. This is why we like to use `this` because... it makes sense! Especially when you use objects.

### `.apply();`

Just as `.call()` is very alike calling a function directly, `.apply()` comes with an other feature. Instead of allowing the programmer to define a set of arguments, an array can be used to define arguments. That allows you to have a dynamic amount of arguments.

You may be familiar with `Math.max()`. This function takes an undefined amount of arguments, and returns the highest number.

```
Math.max(1, 2, 3); // 3
Math.max(1, 3, 2); // 3
Math.max(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3); // 3
```

What if we have an array of numbers, from a feed perhaps, and we want to get the biggest number? This would obviously work:

```
var numbers = [1, 6, 2, 8, 10, 6, 13, 5, 2, 8, 7, 75, 23, 7, 12, 75];

// Prepare "max"
// Anything is greater than -Infinity
var max = -Infinity;

// Loop through all numbers
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    // Compare current number with existing max
    max = Math.max(max, numbers[i]);
}
```

You are wasting precious time looping through all numbers while you can make native code do it for you. That's where `.apply()` comes in handy. Though we have the ability to set `this`, `Math.max()` doesn't use the `this` keyword, so we can just discard it and use `null` instead. It doesn't matter how many elements you have in your array.

```
var numbers = [1, 6, 2, 8, 10, 6, 13, 5, 2, 8, 7, 75, 23, 7, 12, 75];
var max = Math.max.apply(null, numbers); // Apply all array elements as an own argument
```

### Conclusion

There are no (noticeable) disadvantages of any of these methods. Do whatever looks most appropriate for that case or what you like best.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need the "features" that `.call` or `.apply` provide, namely setting `this` or passing an array of arguments, then there is no need to use them.

Calling a function with just `()` is the "normal" way to call a function.